# How to convert HTML to PDF with python3

Tags: python-3.x

How to convert HTML to PDF with python3? i write some code about webView with pyqt5,and i want to convert the html in the webView  to pdf,what should i do?

i have tried to use the html2pdf,but it seem to only support python2.x 
and i have tried to install the wkhtmltox-0.12.2.2_msvc2013-win64.exe and pdfkit,and then use the example code.

```
import pdfkit

pdfkit.from_url('http://google.com', 'out.pdf')
pdfkit.from_file('test.html', 'out.pdf')
pdfkit.from_string('Hello!', 'out.pdf')
```

but i also failed.and the error is following.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "E:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pdfkit\configuration.py", line 21,  in __init__
with open(self.wkhtmltopdf) as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: b''

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
  pdfkit.from_url('http://google.com', 'out.pdf')
File "E:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pdfkit\api.py", line 22, in from_url
configuration=configuration)
File "E:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pdfkit\pdfkit.py", line 38, in __init__
self.configuration = (Configuration() if configuration is None
File "E:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pdfkit\configuration.py", line 27, in __init__
'https://github.com/JazzCore/python-pdfkit/wiki/Installing-wkhtmltopdf' % self.wkhtmltopdf)
OSError: No wkhtmltopdf executable found: "b''"
If this file exists please check that this process can read it.   Otherwise please install wkhtmltopdf - https://github.com/JazzCore/python-pdfkit/wiki/Installing-wkhtmltopdf
```

but i also failed.so what should i do?  My system is window7 x64 ,python's version is 3.4

Comment: i reinstall the wkhtmltox and set path,i work well!!

Comment: Hi zonzely, I've got the same problem. How did you make it work? What did you mean by 'set path'?

Answer (score 5):

Since this hasn't had an accepted answer yet, there is a great library that works in Python 3 that I found after much searching and failed attempts at using PyPDF2, wkhtmltopdf beta branch for Python 3, qpdf, etc. It is weasyprint. I have the related answer and sample code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46508934/1215344).

For completeness sake, from the [documentation](http://weasyprint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

`from weasyprint import HTML
HTML('http://weasyprint.org/').write_pdf('/tmp/weasyprint-website.pdf')`

and it really works that easy.

Comment: Weasy is Way Too Easy. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`'set path'` probably means add `**.exe` to the system environment variable `$Path$`. For example, add `D:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin` to `$Path$`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](//stackoverflow.com/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](//stackoverflow.com/tour)