# Python3 html to pdf

Tags: html, python-3.x, pdf

how to convert HTML to PDF in Python3?
Xhtml2pdf does not work in Python3, got error:

> > > > import xhtml2pdf.pisa as pisa
> > > >         Traceback (most recent call last):
> > > >           File "", line 1, in 
> > > >           File "/home/hound/test/python/test_env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/xhtml2pdf/**init**.py", line 41, in 
> > > >             from xhtml2pdf.util import REPORTLAB22
> > > >           File "/home/hound/test/python/test_env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/xhtml2pdf/util.py", line 302
> > > >             raise Exception, "box not defined right way"
> > > >                            ^
> > > >         SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 5):

The best that I found by far is `weasyprint`.

From the [documentation](http://weasyprint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

`from weasyprint import HTML
HTML('http://weasyprint.org/').write_pdf('/tmp/weasyprint-website.pdf')`

and it really works that easy. Saved me tons of time (after I wasted time trying to get xhtml2pdf and others to work in python 3 but failed.

Comment: quick note a bout weasyprint:  i had a problem with long strings overlapping in a table cell.  couldnt find the right css property to set this to wrap instead of cut off.  Turns out the correct answer was `overflow-wrap: break-word;` with a `width: x;` set too.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error. Apparently for now xhtml2pdf has Python3 support only in its prerelease version - 0.2b1 (for more info see https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xhtml2pdf). I’ve solved the problem by uninstalling the previous xhtml2pdf version and installing the prerelease version

```
pip install --pre xhtml2pdf
```